# Mac shell curl asynchronous call in multiple tabs

Tags: macos, curl, asynchronous

I would like to test if my REST API can handle multiple asynchronous calls.

I write script with `curl` that call my API 1000 times in for loop. I run this script in 5 tabs at the same time.

My question is, is this real asynchronous test, or do terminal execute those calls synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each terminal will execute its calls to commands sequentially, but each terminal window will have its own process (as can be seen in Activity Monitor) and is independent of other terminal windows

[image]

So, with 5 terminal windows, there are 5 asynchronous processes running.

However, we can also run commands and scripts in the background, within a single terminal; achieving multi-threading. When running a terminal command, adding the `&` character tells the terminal to run it in the background, returning the terminal to await more commands.

For example in a single terminal, let's use the command `sleep`, in background mode, 5 times

[image]

We can see from the process list in Activity Monitor, that 5 separate processes are created

[image]

To bring a background process to the foreground, the `fg` command is used, with the relevant process id (pid) as an argument to the command.